# What is xscenario in spec.rb file ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have this legacy app, and trying to figure out this `spec.rb` file.

```
-  scenario 'assign to new rider' do
+  xscenario 'assign to new rider' do
```

Snippet above is from the github. Clearly original author add the letter **x** to the word **scenario**.

But why ? What is the purpose ?

Please guide me to google regarding the reading material to help me understand more.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe just a typo? are you able to run the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tamer for the hint, its a way of pending the test scenario.

[image: xscenario]

Hope this helps anyone else.